# How to make an elasticsearch query use a date_histogram agg to aggregate a given field based on a condition?

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I have the following structure as document in an elasticsearch index:

```
{
    "_source": {
        "description": {
            "logs": [
                {
                    "date": "2023-06-30T11:25:47.776226+00:00",
                    "agent": "AAA"
                },
                {
                    "date": "2023-07-03T15:49:26.024+00:00",
                    "agent": "BBB"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

How can I use a date_histogram type aggregation to aggregate only the dates where description.log.agent == "AAA"?

I have tried to to use the filter aggregation to filter the documents where "agent" is equal to "AAA", but this type of aggregation seems to work at the document level, and since all the documents have logs from both agents, the date_histogram ends up aggregating dates from both agents.

I've also tried to formulate the problem as concise as possible and use chatgpt to create a query but to no avail. Also went through the documentation and could not find anything that seemed like a solution to this problem.

Thank you